# Can't import a data base using PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

We have a database on webserver that works there:~

Apache 2.4.23
PHP    5.5.38
MySQL  5.5.61cll

Through PHPMyAdmin, I saved a file on my laptop.
We have a new webserver and I need to 'transfer' the database here:

Apache 2.4.39
PHP    5.6.36
MySQL  5.6.43cll-lve

Can't import! Can you guide me (step-by-step) on this? I'm a journalist, not a 'computer man'.

I export (a month ago) the database that we work on the original website. It has a lot of articles that we don't want to lose.
I tried to import on the new website to work with it and improve it.
I've received the message that follow:

Error

Static analysis:

> 1 errors were found during analysis.
>
> 1  Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "jos" at position 0)

SQL query:

> jos-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump -- version 4.8.3 -- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/ -- -- Servidor: localhost:3306 -- Tiempo de generación: 18-03-2019 a las 18:52:56 -- Versión del servidor: 5.5.61-cll -- Versión de PHP: 7.2.7 SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO"

MySQL said:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'jos-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
>   -- version 4.8.3

I need your help. I have another question about this, I'll take one step at a time.

Comment: Maybe you should employ/subcontract a MySQL database guy to do this for you? In the long run it would save you lots of stress and frustration. It's maybe 2hrs work maximum.

Comment: As you said, @Martin, it will be more easy. When I tried at 'localhost' level, there're no problem at all. Is on the webserver that I found this problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you exported your database from the phpmyadmin by selecting a database from the left sidebar and then exported them by pressing Export Button you can import that database in phpmyadmin using Import Button.

1. Create a new table by pressing New from the left sidebar where is listed all of your databases
2. Select database where you want to import data
3. Browse to the .sql file which you've downloaded previously using the export command
4. Press Go button at the end of the page.

Comment: That's exactly what I tried... obtaining the text I sent it.

Comment: Sorry... did you mean create a new table in the existing database?

Comment: No, just create new database. What mean this jos at the first line of your sql file? You can open for example in notepad or some other text editor your exported sql database file and see if there is some incorrect mysql syntax. As I can see you have something as 'jos' at line 1 which produce such error. Try to add -- in front of that word to comment that and send what is the error output.

Comment: Something like this '-- jos -- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump ... or just delete that 'jos'

Comment: I've created a new empty database but I can't see it in with phpMyAdmin. I tried to import using the name of the new database and I couldn't. 
There is not that first line with `jos-- ...

Comment: I don't know what is the problem, how you actually get above error if you can't select any database. I've just posted screenshots how I did that on my localhost server.

Comment: @MatijaLukic `jos` is Finnish for `if`

Comment: Apparently, I managed to import the database (confirmed when reviewing the existing databases), but I can not see it in phpMyAdmin ...

Answer (score 0):

[1st step - Click New [image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7O1K.png)

[2nd step - Choose collation and click Create [image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlL8h.png)

[And you will see your database `test` in sidebar db list[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I48RM.png)

After that you click on test database to select them and click button Import(choose sql file with your database and click Go to import data from the sql file)

Comment: There is no "New" in this phpMyAdmin. (can't add a picture of what I have).
Looking in MySQL the new database is there.

Comment: Obviously, you don't have the privilege to use CREATE DATABASE statement. All privileges you can see at the Privileges tab in the header navigation. If you don't have the privilege to CREATE DB or some else restriction, the root user is the only user who can assign some privilege to you. So you have to contact that person who set up MySQL on your server. By default username is 'root' and if the admin didn't set a password, you can log in as the root user.

Comment: I use the creator login and password for the website... I can see now the dbase with MySQL on the website (32.34MB), can't see it with phpMyAdmin at the same place.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. It took time and thanks to your guidance... I got it.
You must create the database in cPanel, import the tables and wait a 'few' hours for it to be enabled in phpMyAdmin.
Thank you, @Matija.